# How to create a Queue in Azure Service Bus using Java?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

I need to provision a Service Bus queue from code but I can't seem to find any details on how to do it. The Azure Service bus library has a unit test that is creating the queue ([link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/ManagementTests.java)) but the maven library I've referenced  doesn't have any of those classes (QueueDescription or ManagementClientAsync).

Has anyone tried creating a queue dynamically from java?

Maven:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> 
  <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId> 
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've referenced doesn't have any of those classes (QueueDescription or ManagementClientAsync).
>
> However this class seem not to be part of azure-core or azure-servicebus librairy and I can seem to find which lib to add to the project to have access to those class.

You mentioned `QueueDescription` or `ManagementClientAsync` seems only available in the [2.0.0-PREVIEW version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/2.0.0-PREVIEW-5). Please have a try to use the following dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-PREVIEW-5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Demo code:**

```
String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
ConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
ManagementClient client = new ManagementClient(connectionStringBuilder);
if(!client.queueExists("queueName"))
{
    QueueDescription queue = client.createQueue("queueName");
}
```

Comment: This is now up to `2.0.0-PREVIEW-7`

Comment: Use `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` if you want to go ahead with the new servicebus library `com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.11.0`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the above mentioned library `com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus` is deprecated and it is encouraged to use the newer `com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus` library as of December 2020.

As per the new library, the process to create a servicebus queue is as follows:

```
ServiceBusAdministrationClient sbAdminClient =  new ServiceBusAdministrationClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(servicebusConnString).buildClient();
    String queueName = "my-queue";
    if(!sbAdminClient.getQueueExists(queueName))
    {
      CreateQueueOptions queueOptions =
          new CreateQueueOptions().setMaxSizeInMegabytes(1024)
              .setMaxDeliveryCount(10)
              .setDefaultMessageTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(1))
              .setLockDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
              .setDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration(true)
              .setPartitioningEnabled(true);
      sbAdminClient.createQueue(queueName,queueOptions);
    }
```